# Time Complexity of inserting a vector to a vector of vectors in C++

Tags: time-complexity

I was solving a question on LeetCode, where I had to generate all possible subsets of a given set of numbers.

Although, the solution makes sense to me, I am unable to understand the derivation of time complexity for those solutions.

A solution I found there was:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> subs = {{}};
        for (int num : nums) {
            int n = subs.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                subs.push_back(subs[i]);  <---- LINE X
                subs.back().push_back(num); <---- LINE Y
            }
        }
        return subs;
    }
};
```

It is an iterative solution to solve the problem.
What I don't understand is the time complexity of the given solution and **more importantly**, the complexities of Line X and Line Y.

Does copying subs[i] take O(n) time and then pushing back take another O(n) time, or is it an O(1) step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First tings first:

Line X does a copy subs[i] and creates a new vector.
In terms of vector length $n$ this step is $O(n)$.

Line Y is amortized O(1). (The vector might need to reallocate making it O(n) in the worst case; to avoid reallocation see @MSalters post.)

The runtime of the whole procedure is a bit more difficult.
At the $i$-th number `subs` contains every possible subset of all numbers so far.
Thus length of subs $=2^i$, but we are interested in how many numbers we need to copy. this can be calculate with [the sum of all subset sizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610110/total-size-of-all-subsets-of-a-set-is-n-cdot2n-1#:%7E:text=4-,Total%20size%20of%20all%20subsets%20of%20a,n%E2%8B%852n%E2%88%921) which is $i2^{i-1}$ (meaning at step $i$ we have to copy $i2^{i-1}$ numbers and make $2^i$ push operations).
$$O\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i2^{i-1}+2^i\right) = O(n2^n)$$
The complexity on the right makes sense, all sizes of all vectors in `subs` will be $n2^{n-1}$ in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a bit of C++ knowledge.

`push_back` will copy or move the argument. Copying a vector is O(n), moving it is O(1). In this case, the argument on line X is `subs[i]`, which does not allow a move. It will be copied (good, since we need it later).

On line Y, the argument is just a single integer. Copying an integer is O(1), essentially by definition.

But besides copying the argument, `push_back` may also need to move all the existing arguments if there's a need to reallocate memory. Vectors have exponential growth, so this doesn't happen on every `push_back`. As a result, adding N elements to an empty vector will only cause O(log N) realloactions which requires moving O(N) elements.

C++ has a solution to this. `vector.reserve(N)` will perform one allocation so that `push_back` up to `vector.size()==N` will not cause reallocations.